# Ls and input redirection

Tags: bash, redirection, input

I'd like to redirect contents of a file to `ls` command input:

```
ls -l < /home/john/1.txt
```

where `1.txt` content is just:

```
/etc
```

I expected `ls` to list the content of file defined in `/home/jonh1.txt` - that is `/etc` dir
but it seems to ignore the input stream -  still lists the contents of the current dir insted of `/etc` dir as defined in `/home/jonh1.txt` file.

Comment: [Why do some commands not read from their standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140522/108618), [Unix pipe into `ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18210956), [Piping the contents of a file to `ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44739947).

Comment: What's the goal, to get a ls-like listing of specific files (from a list in a separate textfile)? `stat` might be useful

Comment: [Why your question may have been downwoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/355310).

Answer (score 3):

> it seems to ignore the input stream

Yes. The `ls` program *never* uses the input stream, because it wasn't written to read anything from the input stream. This is not something that comes automatically with any Unix program – it has to be implemented separately.

Do not confuse the input stream (stdin) with the command-line arguments (argv); the former is an actual stream which can be read from line-by-line, while the latter is a simple read-only array of words. In your case, both are present and contain different data.

(Why shouldn't it be automatic for all programs? Well, take *sort* or *cat* or *grep* as an example. These programs accept different kinds of values – file names as arguments, but text as stdin contents. So you can pipe any command to `| sort`, and it sorts the input. But if stdin and command-line were the same thing, you couldn't pipe anything into `| sort` anymore because it would think that the pipe input was a list of filenames. Or vice versa, you couldn't give it filenames because it'd just sort the names.)

For an alternative take, see [this explanation on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739947/piping-the-contents-of-a-file-to-ls) (which you already got in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Try using xargs:

```
xargs ls -l < /home/john/1.txt
```

Comment: I didn't asked about an alternate way but WHY doesn't ls ignores input stream.

Comment: Please edit your question to more explicitly ask that. Right now your question doesn't even include the word *why*, making it hard to know this is what you want from an answer.

Comment: @Mulligun007 No, you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you write any command line program that takes input from the user, you'll see very clearly what's going on.  If a program has a read/readLine(different languages might give it a different name), statement, so, the program prompts the user for input, then you can also pipe or redirect that input in using `|` or `<`

If you look at a program that takes input, you see like with `more` or `less`, if you type it with no input `$more<ENTER>`, then it prompts for input. By piping data to it, it stops it prompting for input.  If we run sed with no parameters `$sed<ENTER>` then sure it gives an error, and we can't do `$echo abc|sed<ENTER>` either. But if we do `$sed 's/a/b/'<ENTER>` then it prompts for input. And that's why  `echo abc|sed 's/a/b/'<ENTER>`  works.

You can see this if you write a program even as simple as Hello World but that takes input like the program prompts for a word and if the person types 'abc' it says "Hello abc". You'll be able to pipe to that program. It doesn't take any extra programming to get piping and redirection of input to work. If the program accepts keyboard input from the user then piping and redirection to it will work and then the program won't prompt for input.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***

*As Kamil Maciorowski pointed out in a comment below, the following is not the right way to go.*

> If `/home/john/1.txt` is guaranteed to contain exactly one path then [you should definitely double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). If the file may contain more than one path and you deliberately rely on word splitting, then this is not the right way to supply arbitrary paths.

**Original post (bad example)**

You can use the following:

```
ls -l $(cat /home/john/1.txt)
```

See `> man bash` section **Command Substitution**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Community Sorry, what is not clear?

Comment: If `/home/john/1.txt` is guaranteed to contain exactly one path then [you should definitely double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). If the file may contain more than one path and you deliberately rely on word splitting, then this is not the right way to supply arbitrary paths.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for the remark. Feel free to vote it down. I will leave it there as a "bad example" for future reference.